# Session is null in RouteBase::GetRouteData

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, redirect

I need to do a 301 redirect for certain urls. Following is the skeleton of the code

```
public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
  {
     .
     .
     .

      if (newUrl.Length > 0)
      {
          response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
          response.RedirectLocation = newUrl;
          response.End();
      }
  }
```

This works well. It redirects correct for certain Urls. However, I want to have a way to detect that a 301 redirect happened in the next request. So I wish to use a flag as part of Session variables. Something like this:

```
httpContext.Session["RedirectHappened"] = true;
```

But Session object is null. How do I access session? Or is there any other way to detect if the current 200 OK request was a result of a previous 301 redirect.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fixed this issue using MVC's `RedirectToActionPermanent` in the corresponding controller and there we are setting the flag using Session object.

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
    Session["RedirectFromOldUrl"] = true;

    return RedirectToActionPermanent("action", "controller");
 }
```